# I am having 2 external monitors connected to my laptop, and would like to identify which monitor is touch id enabled using c#/C++

Tags: c#, c++, .net, wmi-query

Out of the 3 monitors if 2 are touch id enabled, when I try to identify which monitor is touchscreen enabled programitacally, I am able to get the name of the first monitor but the other monitor shows as a HID device while using ITouch interface. I would like to know to identify the second monitors id as well.

I tried POINTER_DEVICE_INFO win api to get the Monitor info for touchscreen. hmonitor out variable is not giving the monitor information correctly.